# How to iterate the irregularly-named children of an Xml.XmlElement in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an XML file of the following format:

```
<xml>
    <data>
        <foo float="99.0"/>
        <bar float="12.0"/>
        <tribble bool="true"/>
        ...
        <flibble int="1"/>
    </data>
</xml>
```

If I fetch that data in Powershell, I can see all the child elements of data with a Get-Memeber:

```
> $xmlData = [xml](Get-Content myfile.xml)
> $xmlData.data | Get-Member
    ...
    foo     Property    System.Xml.XmlElement ...
    bar     Property    System.Xml.XmlElement ...
    tribble Property    System.Xml.XmlElement ...
    ...
```

And I can access each child element individually.  But how would I iterate over all the children, processing them with pipes?  I'd love to be able to write something like this:

```
> $xmlData.data.Children | ?{$_ -eq "foo"}
```

...But alas that's just wishful thinking.

EDIT: Ok so I can reflect on the properties like this:

```
> $xmlData.data | get-member -memberType Property | ?{$_.Name -eq "foo"}
```

But I can't then go from the property (above I'm operating on a MemberDefinition) to the actual child element.  Or can I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First:** You need to use `Get-Member -Force` ... which will show you *everything*.  Note with particular interest the get_* methods which represent properties which for some reason aren't exposed as properties in PowerShell. So when you see `get_ChildNodes` in the member list, it means there's a .ChildNodes property on the object (even though PowerShell hides it for some reason).

**Second:** So therefore, there are lots of ways, including the get-member method you hinted at (I append the `Format-Table` because it makes it easier to tell that you got something):

1. `$xmlData.data.SelectNodes("*") | ft name, OuterXml`
2. `$xmlData.data.ChildNodes | ft name, OuterXml`
3. `$xmlData.data | gm -type Property | % { $xmlData.data.($_.Name) } |

   Where { $_ -is [Xml.XmlElement] } | ft Name, OuterXml`

Comment: I believe the reason get_ChildNodes isn't listed by default is that folks like me complained that the output of Get-Member was too damn noisy by default.  Especially when it listed get_Prop, set_Prop and Prop.  Not even Visual Studio Intellisense lists compiler generated methods. And you've found that you can force PowerShell to display those methods.

Comment: If you use the `-View All` parameter to `Get-Member`, it will show you all the properties, but it still won't show you the get_Prop methods. From reading the man page for `Get-Member` I guess properties like `OuterXml` are in the base .Net object, but not adapted for the PowerShell extended type system.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason `Get-Member` doesn't display the other properties `System.Xml.XmlElement` provides. Here is the full member list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement_members.aspx

As you can see, there is a `ChildNodes` property, so you can do this:

`(Select-Xml -Path "file.xml" -XPath "//xml/data").Node.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "foo" }`

Comment: Huh, interesting that get-member isn't always exhaustive. I'll check msdn next time.  Thanks!